# Select distinct and date difference in Linq to SQL from two dataTables

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have tried the below linq to sql query

```
 DataTable StudentTable=StudentTimeReport.Tables[0];
 DataTable RoundEndDateTable=RoundEndDates.Tables[0];
          var studentData = from student in StudentTable.AsEnumerable()
                              join Rounds in RoundEndDateTable.AsEnumerable() on student.Field<string>("strActivityName") equals Rounds.Field<string>("strActivityName")
                              select student;
```

The two datatables are as follows

**RoundEndDateTable**

```
ActionName          End Date
SQLs              8/31/2014 0:00
Gas Lekage        9/18/2014 0:00
Test Activity     9/20/2014 0:00
```

**StudentTable**

```
ActionName          Player ID    Completed Date
Gas Lekage            810045    9/16/2014 14:38
Test Activity         810015    9/16/2014 14:39
```

I need to get the date difference for player, action like below

```
Player ID   Action Name     Date difference
 810015     Gas leakage       2
 810015     Test Activity     4
```

I am not sure how should I get the above table having date difference using Linq to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want the two tables mapped by `ActionName`, and you want to find the difference in days between `CompletedDate` and `Date` for each player.

```
SELECT PlayerID, ActionName, MAX(DATEDIFF(DAY, Table1.Date, Table2.CompletedDate)) AS DateDifference
FROM Table1
    INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ActionName = Table2.ActionName
GROUP BY PlayerID, ActionName
```

In the interest of assuring a single result per player, as you'll notice, I take the maximum difference. It's certainly your call whether you need that or not, but I took it that you did, given the title of your question.

Comment: he wanted it in LINQ To Sql :)

Answer (score 1):

we can use datediff function

```
select B.ActionName, 
       B.PlayerId,  
       DATEDIFF(day, A.Date, B.completedDate) as difference
FROM B
INNER JOIN A
ON B.ActionName = A.ActionName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var studentData = from redt in RoundEndDateTable
             join st in StudentTable on redt.ActionName equals st.ActionName
             select new
{
    st.PlayerId,
    st.ActionName,
    ((DateTime)st.Completed - (DateTime)redt.Date).TotalDays
}.ToList();
```

Please check this once.

Comment: it says could not find an implementation of the quero of pattern system.data.DataTable

Comment: are you missing any using statement?

Comment: you are using AsEnumerable extension method on DataTable. This method is defined in DataTableExtensions class. So I guess problem is here.

Answer (score 1):

I got the below code working for me

```
 var studentData = (from redt in RoundEndDateTable.AsEnumerable()
                   join st in StudentTable.AsEnumerable() 
                   on redt.Field<string>("strActivityName") 
                   equals st.Field<string>("strActivityName")
                   select new
                   {
                      actionName = st.ItemArray[0],
                      associateId  = st.ItemArray[1],
                      completedDate = st.ItemArray[2],
                      EndDate = redt.ItemArray[1],
                      DateDifference = DateTime.Parse(redt.ItemArray[1].ToString()) - 
                      DateTime.Parse(st.ItemArray[2].ToString())
                   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Naughtily stolen from Mukund and (hopefully) fixed:

```
var studentData = (from redt in RoundEndDateTable.AsEnumerable()
             join st in StudentTable.AsEnumerable() on redt["ActionName"] equals st["ActionName"]
             select new
             {
                 PlayerId = (int)st["PlayerId"],
                 ActionName = (string)st["ActionName"],
                 Completed = (DateTime)st["Completed"],
                 Date = (DateTime)redt["Date"]
             })
             .Select(sd => new {
                 sd.PlayerId,
                 sd.ActionName,
                 (sd.Completed - sd.Date).TotalDays
             })
             .ToList();
```

If you get `InvalidCastExceptions`, check that the data types match. Maybe you need to actually parse the values.

Comment: i am getting error if i am not adding .asEnumerable

Comment: Be more specific, please.

Comment: there is an error that i am getting
it says could not find an implementation of the quero of pattern system.data.DataTable

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you have an actual DataTable and have the DataRow objects in memory already. The changed solution should (mostly) work, although it's pretty ugly. I'd suggest to actually use Linq to SQL (the OR mapper).